# How to interact between Models inside model.py?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

There is something I want to do but I don't know how to do it.
in this case I have 2 Models in project named **1.Music 2.Artist**

**1. Music** Model is saving music details such as musicName,artistName,genre,etc... 
**2. Artist** Model has only one job and that is saving Artist names.

I want to write a code for my models to when I'm adding a new music in **admin panel**, **Music Model** checks the Artist Model for **existence artist names** and if artist name existed => just add music details and if artist name not existed Then add a new artist in **Artist Model**.

This is my sample **model.py** code:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Music(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: you said if artist is not exist then add new artist, so first you have to add artist then you can add music object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ForeignKey` in artist field instead of `CharField`. So, your `Music` model will look like this:

```
class Music(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

When you want to get musics by spesific artist in views.py, use filter():

```
musics = Music.objects.filter(artist=1)
```